# How to update an AwsBatchOperator task code in Airflow?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow, aws-batch

I have an airflow-scheduler and airflow-webserver deployed on an EC2 machine on AWS. I use this airflow-scheduler to execute a DAG with an `AwsBatchOperator` task. This task executes a python script present on EC2 machine. Here is the code of the DAG:

```py
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.batch import AwsBatchOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'admin',
    'concurrency': 3,
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': None,
    'end_date': None,
    'schedule_interval': None,
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='my-dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='My DAG',
    schedule_interval='00 03 * * *',
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    tags=['dev'],
)

task = AwsBatchOperator(
  dag=dag,
  job_name= 'my-job-name',
  job_definition= 'arn:aws:batch:eu-central-1:XXXX:job-definition/my-job-name',
  job_queue= 'arn:aws:batch:eu-central-1:XXXX:job-queue/my-job-name',
  region_name= 'eu-central-1',
  task_id= 'my-task-id',
  overrides={
    'command': ['python3', './my_python_script.py']
  },
  parameters= {}
)
```

The python script `my_python_script.py` is on the EC2 machine where airflow is deployed, in directory `/home/ubuntu`.

I had a typo raising an error in this python script. I corrected it and push the corrected script on EC2 machine. However when I execute the DAG, I still get the error caused by the typo I corrected. So here is my question:

**How can I refresh my DAG to ensure that it uses the version of my script that is present on my EC2 machine?**

#### What I've tried

- Refresh DAG by clicking on "refresh" button on Airflow web interface
- Wait for automatic DAG refresh by airflow-scheduler
- Delete DAG and wait for refresh
- Recompile python script on EC2 machine with command `python -m compileall`

Comment: I didn't work with AWS Batch, but maybe you can try uploading a copy of the file like `my_python_script_copy.py`, with the same code and change the name in the `overrides` parameters to check what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To update code of an `AwsBatchOperator` task, you need to update docker image used by your AWS batch job with your new code and not the code present on EC2 machine where airflow is deployed**

`AwsBatchOperator` can execute code present in AWS batch job definition docker image but cannot execute code present in EC2 machine where airflow is deployed.

When you use `AwsBatchOperator`, you set which job definition you want to use. For my case, it is `arn:aws:batch:eu-central-1:XXXX:job-definition/my-job-name`. This job definition contains the docker image where your command will be executed. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/batch/latest/userguide/Batch_GetStarted.html

I was confused as it was the same codebase that was present on EC2 machine and docker image. So instead of updating code on EC2 machine where airflow is deployed, I just have to create a new docker image with the new version of my code and make my AWS batch job uses this new image.